# Linear regression with error dispersion dependent on the independent variable

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, heteroscedasticity, t-distribution, point-estimation

Suppose $y=ax+z$ where $x, y, z$ are random variables with range in $\mathbf R$, $\mathbf E[x]=0$, the probability distribution $p(z|x)$ is

1) normal distribution $N(0,\sigma(x)^2)$ with mean $0$ and standard deviation $\sigma(x)$ as an unknown function of $x$;

2) student t-distribution $t_{\nu(x)}$ with degrees of freedom $\nu(x)$ an unknown function of $x$,

and $a$ is an unknown constant. Suppose $(x_i,y_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a set of tuples of sample observation of $(x,y)$. How do we estimate the following functions?

1) $(a,\sigma(x))$;

2) $(a,\nu(x))$.

---

Note: This is not the heteroscedasticity problem in the conventional sense where the dispersion parameter depends on the index $i$. The dispersion parameter now depends on the independent variable $x$.

Comment: a little more context would be nice. It would be fairly straightforward to write down the maximum likelihood equations for this, and *maybe* to solve for the MLE (I haven't tried). Computationally, you could consider this (at least the first, and maybe the second) a *generalized least squares* problem, and fit it (e.g. with `gls()` from the `nlme` package in R.

Comment: @BenBolker: Thank you. I agree that MLE is a way to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is you can reasonably estimate $a$ with OLS in (1) and a maybe a more robust estimation in (2) like [like IRLS](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/236676/can-you-give-a-simple-intuitive-explanation-of-irls-method-to-find-the-mle-of-a/237384#237384)
 (though [maybe OLS might still be ok](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/152674/why-is-the-normality-of-residuals-barely-important-at-all-for-the-purpose-of-e)).

Estimating $\sigma(x)$ and $\nu(x)$ is harder. I think you need to decide how to parameterize or quantize wrt $x$. For instance, if you choose some function with parameters $\theta$, and define your estimate to be $\hat{\sigma}(x)=f(x;\theta)$, then you can numerically fit $\theta$ by maximizing the log-likelihood over the dataset $(x_i, z_i)=(x_i,y_i-ax_i)$. The choice of $f$ represents some level of "prior" over $\sigma(x)$ or $\nu(x)$.

I guess you can also *jointly* estimate $a$ and $\sigma$ or $\nu$ together by combining the two optimization approaches above in an alternating manner.

Related Links

- [MLE for $t$-distributed errors](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/350550/mle-for-linear-regression-student-t-distributed-error)
- [Estimating parameters of $t$ distributions](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/63647/estimating-parameters-of-students-t-distribution)
- [Non-normal OLS residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29731/regression-when-the-ols-residuals-are-not-normally-distributed) (also [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/173621/linear-regression-any-non-normal-distribution-giving-identity-of-ols-and-mle))

Comment: +1 and thank you for the prompt and informative answer. Let me read through the links.

Comment: @Hans hopefully it helps. PS I think you can get/estimate $\sigma$ from robust standard errors in (1). The same might also work for (2). Perhaps see  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/275925/linear-regression-with-changing-variance or maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258485/simulate-linear-regression-with-heteroscedasticity

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance of your answer. Thank you again for your richly informative answer.